# How can I add "required" attribute in Spring-MVC

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

How can I add "required" attribute in Spring-MVC?

I want the ending tag to look like this

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" required>
```

So I am doing the following in my JSP

```
<form:input path="usrname" maxlength="12" required/>
```

But I am gettng a error

Answer (score 32):

I found the fix. my code had to me like this

```
<form:input path="usrname" maxlength="12" required="required"/>
```

Now it works.. :)